# How to align text center in a Box which (text) is Vertical -rl aligned

Tags: css

I have a Box and the text i want to show as vertical ,

I used `writing-mode : vertical-rl` to align it so , as :

[image: Image of box is as]

I am trying to get the text to center :

using `text-align : center` or `justify-content : center` but nothing worked

Present CSS used is as:

[image: current CSS]

I have also gone through few other SO Q's but nothing worked

req O/p :

- Box size varies dynamically, but text should be aligned at center (for any padding suggestions).. May I know how could i achieve this .. any help is much appreciated , TIA

  [image: req o/p]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [align-items](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/):

```
.sapMText {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: normal;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate , actually i have tried align-items but the thing is display: has inline-block overrided by other css , now changing to flex did the trick :)

Comment: For smaller text , how could i align it vertically center mate ?

Comment: To center vertically just add justify-content: center like you had before.

Answer (score 1):

Put text in span tag `<span id="text">text vertical ...</span>` and give following style to it :

```
    #text {
writing-mode : vertical-rl;
margin-left: 50%;}
```