# How do I horizontally align vertical text in a table with CSS?

Tags: css, text-alignment, tablecell, vertical-text

I have some `writing-mode: vertical-rl` text in a table cell. By default, it gets pushed to the left side of the cell, but I want to center it or push it right. If I were handling `horizontal-tb` text, I would use `text-align: center` or `vertical-align` but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding `horizontal-align` property.

In this example, I want the vertical text centered in the cell:

[image: Vertical text is pushed left, but I want it centered]

I am testing this in Firefox 91.

Here is a jsfiddle for the above image: https://jsfiddle.net/a965ej2x/

And the corresponding code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>This is my heading</th>
  </tr>
  <td>
    しょうがない
  </td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I think `display: flex; justify-content: center;` should do it

Comment: it works fine on Chrome by the way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732139/vertical-align-middle-does-not-align-to-the-middle-in-firefox, note that `center` is not a valid value for `vertical-align`, it should be `middle`.

Comment: @arieljuod Whoops, yes, should be vertical-align: middle in the example.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Does that imply this is a bug in Firefox?

Comment: @ShamPooSham setting `display: flex` on the <td> causes the table cell to no longer stretch to the size of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug on Firefox that you can fix by adding an extra element where you apply the `writing-mode`

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}

td span {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  vertical-align:top; /* remove bottom whitespace */
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>This is my heading</th>
    </tr>
    <td>
      <span>しょうがない</span>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm accepting this solution of adding an additional <span> knowing that it's kind of a hacky workaround. It also works around a different but related Chrome bug, so bonus points for that too.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188268/how-to-align-text-center-in-a-box-which-text-is-vertical-rl-aligned) should work.

```css
td {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: normal;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>This is my heading</th>
          </tr>
          <td>
            しょうがない
          </td>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```